# source code from APK

Tags: java, android, apk, decompiler, dex

I have searching in search Engine regarding convert dex file to jar file but I got failure to find dex2jar file in code.Google.com

I have getting basic idea from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file).

But when I download file from dex2jar-0.0.9.8.zip form [**here**](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/downloads/list), I unable to found dex2jar.jar file so can you tell me else where I can find file?

Comment: do u want to extract the source file of android app?right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Extract the dex2jar-0.0.9.8.zip file and move to desktop folder like dex2jar-0.0.9.7...then take the android app classes.dex file and move to this directory ...open the terminal and change to your dex2jar directory..type this command

```
./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex
```

you will get  classesdex2.jar file and you can open this file using java decompiler...

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to extracted folder in command prompt and run command "dex2jar your.apk"  and its output will be jar file. This jar file can be viewed in jd-gui window.

check the link below , it shows with snapshots

http://a4apphack.com/security/sec-code/extract-android-apk-from-market-and-decompile-it-to-java-source

Answer (score 1):

Extract **dex2jar-0.0.9.8.zip** and copy classes.dex, which is extarcted from apk file to that folder and use below command instead of **dex2jar classes.dex** because it is deprecated

```
./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex
```

Answer (score 0):

dex2jar is not an actual jar.
if you look closely, you will see that there is d2j-dex2jar.bat instead :)
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

extract the dex2jar-0.0.9.8.zip and  in your terminal go to the dex2jar-0.0.9.8 folder and run the delow command

```
  $d2j-dex2jar.sh -f -o test_apk-debug.jar ./Desktop/YourApk.apk
```

//now you can see the jar file. if you open the jar you can fine the class files under you package name.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, Thus I downloaded my file from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/files/).

While the file is downloading, go to your .apk file. Rename the .apk to .zip and **extract zip file (which was apk once)** inside a new folder.

Now as the file is been downloaded "dex2jar-0.0.9.15.zip". Extract this file inside new folder you just create and you will have a folder "/dex2jar-0.0.9.15".

Copy your "classes.dex" file from new folder to "/dex2jar-0.0.9.15" and now open Terminal and switch inside the /dex2jar-0.0.9.15 folder. And run command

```
tamta@tamta:~/new_folder/dex2jar-0.0.9.15$ ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex
```

This will create a file classes-dex2jar.jar for you inside the same folder.

Until now you had .dex file known as Dalvik Executable. If you use **apktool** you only get .smali , which is also not in a understandable form, So now we use "JAVA Decompiler" but we can understand JAVA and to convert do the following.

Goto Download [Link](http://jd.benow.ca/)

And download JD-GUI.

As you open JD-GUI:

```
goto folder
/new_folder/dex2jar-0.0.9.15

and open: "classes-dex2jar.jar"
```

Now again goto >file>Save All Sources

and save the file with the name src.

Now extract src, and **enjoy reading android source code**.