# how to get an .apk from my phone to restore my source files

Tags: android, apk, root

I was importing a .java file from one project to another in Eclipse.  In doing so, Eclipse deleted all my .java files and my .apk files from the source project.  I know I can rebuild them from an .apk file but the only current one is on my LG phone.

How can I get the .apk off my phone an onto my PC?  Do I have to root the phone so that I can see the Data folder?  I have Android File Manager but I don't see how to upload to the pc.
Thanks,
Gary

Comment: see this answer `http://stackoverflow.com/a/12733518/826657`, and adb pull to get the apk .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't actually need root to pull your APKs from your device. This command will list the location of the APK:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

Then you can use adb pull:

```
adb pull <APK path from previous command>
```

You shouldn't need root for this.

Comment: Thanks, this would solve my problem.  I found that Eclipse did not delete my files but moved them all somewhere.  So I got them all back.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the file in your phone's File Manager, why not simply email it to yourself?