# Transfer Android app from galaxy to pc

Tags: android

I have made an android app using eclipse and run in on my galaxy device.
then My App files on my computer deleted somehow so I lost all my project(no backup).
I have the app on my galaxy and I can run in it fine.
There is a any way to transfer it to pc so I can reuse it?
Thanks a-lottttt
Zachinio

Comment: Look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device

Comment: Keep in mind that although you can get the apk, you can't get the source code of the project this way. You will probably need to reverse engineer the dex files.

Comment: For reverse engineering you might want to have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to reuse it as in get back to the source code? Or just reinstall the APK to some other devices via your PC?

If the latter, it should be straight forward via `adb put` and `adb get`.

If the former, it depends whether you used Proguard to obfuscate your code... If it is a relatively small app, you can still get the code but not necessarily with the same symbols you originally gave it), using `AntiLVL`.

Comment: I need it for the source code..Can you explain me more how to do it?

Comment: @Zachinio Google `AntiLVL`. There are very clear & detailed instructions on how to download it and use it.