# Extract Gif from APK

Tags: android, apk, loader

I need to extract the loader.gif from APK of Facebook it is possible?

[image]

I like this animation =(

Comment: An APK is just a JAR with specified content, which is just a ZIP with specified content.... so open the APK with any ZIP tool and find the image in it.

Comment: i ha tried the .apk not contains .gif or png or "loading" file

Comment: I don't think its a gif file. they have created the animation. gif files as such are not supported in android.

Comment: I assume that you have checked the license terms and conditions and that they permit reverse engineering and re-use of their property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open the Facebook apk with a zip-tool like WinRar or 7zip. You can navigate through the folders then.

If you don't find the gif, there are many websites like http://www.ajaxload.info/ where you can generate such gifs.

Maybe you should have a look at this question, too. [Reverse engineering from an APK file to a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project)

Answer (score -1):

Add **facebookImage** to your drawable folder
write the following code in splash.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
>
<ImageView
    android:id = "@+id/facebookImage"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
    android:scaleType = "fitXY"     
    android:contentDescription="@string/decriptionImage"
    />    
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </ProgressBar></RelativeLayout>
```

and **setContentView(R.layout.splash)** in an Activity which you want