# How to convert android app files into that the sdk can read?

Tags: android, sdk

I have a rooted android phone. I used RootFile file manager to go into /data/data. Once their, I selected an app at random for testing purposes. I then copied and pasted to my dropbox, and tried to open the file with the the Android SDK on my computer. It opened nothing, leaving me with a blank page. How do I convert the file so the SDK can show me the programming, or how can I set the SDK to do that. Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "take" an app (or apk) and see the "programming".

It is possible to see the design part (xml layout files, images,...) but the rest is encrypted

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that apk file is closed binary file, it is compiled and you can't open it with AndroidStudio and it's not ment to be opened.
Now that we have established this, you can look into subject that is called *reverse engineering*, basically trying to get source code out of compiled binaries. This is not for beginners. You can check out some of these links
[Reverse engineering from an APK file to a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project)
https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/

But as far as I understand this is definitely not what you want. Download some example android project source code to import into Android studio.

Comment: If this helped you then please mark question as answered.