# viewing android app source code

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I was wondering, is there any way I could download an app from the google play store and view/modify the source code?

I'd like to break down some existing professional apps and see how they're designed, and possibly try to add features for personal use.

Is is possible to do this?  I imagine it would be a bit restrictive since programmers wouldn't want others to steal their source code and republish an app under another name.

Anyone have any insight on this matter?

Comment: [App for reverse engineering](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse engineering from an APK file to a project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project)

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend checking out samples from https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html

Comment: He's asking about reverse engineering.

Comment: It's not related to samples at all.

Comment: He (probably) is wanting to see some coding standards and conventions from looking at existing code. using those samples he can do just that.