# Not able to extract the XML files from APK

Tags: java, android, xml, apk

I'm trying to retrieve the source code from the APK file. When I tied extracting the XML files from the APK File(Which I got by following the steps 1-3 from this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16544681/3212998][1] ),  I'm getting an empty directory after executing this command

`$apktool d "appName".apk`  :

And the following traceback :

```
.2/bin/apktool -> ../libexec/apktool
I: Loading resource table...
I: Loaded.
I: Decoding AndroidManifest.xml with resources...
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.directory.PathNotExist: AndroidManifest.xml
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ResFileDecoder.decodeManifest(ResFileDecoder.java:133)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.decode(AndrolibResources.java:218)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.decodeResourcesFull(Androlib.java:115)
        at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:114)
        at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:146)
        at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: brut.directory.PathNotExist: AndroidManifest.xml
        at brut.directory.AbstractDirectory.getFileInput(AbstractDirectory.java:103)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ResFileDecoder.decodeManifest(ResFileDecoder.java:129)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about violating software licensing terms and conditions.  Download the source code or, if it not open source, ask the developers for it.

Comment: It's my own APK and I have lost the source code and I want to retrieve it and not to re develop it from scratch.

Comment: Please forgive me, but how can we possibly know that this is true?  There are sites that are not so protective of software IP rights but this site is mainly curated by developers so you will not receive help here.

Comment: @Simon I could understand, but if that's the case, question that corresponds to the link that I have quoted in my question should also be closed.

Comment: So because something happened in the past, it makes it OK now?