# How to open files on eclipse from phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I don't have access to the source code of my app, but I have my phone that the last build was installed on. Is there a way to edit it from the stuff I have?

Comment: If you didn't obfuscate it you could try your hand at reverse engineering. That is all I will say on the matter, however, because I do not know if you're trying to reverse engineer your app, or someone else's; considering you should have the source code.

Comment: use [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your build then there are many ways to get source of you application. It is called "Reverse Engineering".

Such tools like [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/)

Here is complete reference with example for you. Hope this will helps you.

http://www.technotalkative.com/part-9-reverse-engineering-android-applications/