# Rebuild Android Studio project from phone app?

Tags: android

I created an android app using Android Studio. Before I could publish it on the play store my hard drive crashed and the data was lost. I tested it using my phone so I have the app installed. I would like to know if there's any way I can recover the source code from the app on my phone so I don't have to start from scratch. Thanks in advance -Tyler

Comment: You can decompile it, but you're going to lose all your comments, possibly variable names, and if you used proguard its going to be 100% obfuscated.

This is why you should always use a source control system on a remote server.  That way if the server corrupts you have your local copy to backup from, and if your hard drive dies you have the server you can checkout of.  There's plenty of free ones so there's no excuse to ever not use one.

Answer (score -1):

A question similar to yours (the same actually) was already answered here:

[Reverse engineering from an APK file to a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project)

Your app APK is located in **/data/app**

You can get it on your computer using adb

```
adb pull /data/app/*name of your app APK*
```

Hope it helps!