# How to find the coding of APP in Android

Tags: android

I developed An Android App,but the hard drive of my computer is dead. Can I find codes of my APP which I have installed on my Android Phone? What's software that I need?

Comment: Restore the code from a backup of your computer, or from your version control system.

Comment: If you have not used version control, consider to use version control, make regular backups

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project

Comment: check this [get source code from apk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)