# Can I debug .apk that I didn't create

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, apk

I have an APK and have run it on Android device. Can I debug it without compiling it? For example, use Android Studio's `attach to the process` function? I'm interested in breakpoints debugging

Comment: Last I checked, it's even possible to extract all Java code from APKs, so it should be possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can. Using debug apk you can find memory traces in DDMS.

Comment: thanks, but for that I'd need apk to be built as debug, correct? and I'm also interested in breakpoints debugging - is this possible?