# Get previous code in android studio

Tags: java, android

Hey i have this issue where I first created an app, put it on playstore and then i tried to integrate google adsense into it later. I had to change some code in the build file which has now completely ruined my project and i can't even revert back my changes since i had closed android studio.

I've spent hours trying to fix the code but it just wouldnt work. I need to see what have i done wrong. In the previous version it was working fine. Is there any way to see the code in the previous apk? or reset changes or anything like that in android studio?

Comment: Impressive some people still does not use VCS these days. Please read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control and learn from your failure.

Comment: Is there any solution for now?

Comment: My suggestion -> Try the free versions of bitbucket or use github to store your project in safe place..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Android Studio has a code history feature which allows you to see previous versions of a corresponding file. Just right click on a file in the IDE's file explorer and you will see this option.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that. Where do i right click?

Comment: You, sir, are a LIFE SAVER

Answer (score 14):

Right click the file in android studio, Local History -> Show History. Maybe you can see old version of file.

If not, here is the certain solution: download old apk from Play store, use [Dex2jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/files/) to decompile old .dex file and see codes with [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/).

Or you can use [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) too.

Comment: Right click on which file?

Comment: Your possible Java files that contains problems.

Comment: @AxeManTOBO Android studio -> Right click on your project folder -> you can see local history

Comment: @OzgurGUL for decompiling easy process check my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27981520/3879847

Comment: @Ranjith Kumar, Sometime learning the hard way is better :)

Comment: but if we get the same output in easy way why we stay with hard way??

Comment: @RanjithKumar is there any way to see the changes in the build.gradle? The ways you've mentioned in the answer dont have a way to get gradle file of the app

Comment: @AxeManTOBO yes.. that give the partial files(java,xml,manifest) only.. not entire project..

Comment: @AxeManTOBO but local history is good idea.. r u try this?

Comment: Thank you all so much. Checking local history worked for me

Comment: You, sir, are a LIFE SAVER.

Comment: Glad it helped Mr.Shounak Ray ;)

Comment: Wait can they see my code that easily? I see the power of obfuscators now!

Answer (score 1):

You could try googling for an .apk decompiler and try to decompile your old .apk. You may get mixed results but if you are desperate that is one option.

But from now on, make sure to use git for source control in your apps. Android Studio makes it really easy to use git.