# Terminal - dex2jar mac

Tags: java, macos, terminal, dex2jar

I am trying to convert `.dex` to`.jar`, I have dex2jar on my desktop and I also placed the classes.dex file on my desktop.

I navigated to `d2j-dex2jar.sh` using `MacBook-Pro:dex2jar Username$ ./d2j-dex2jar.sh` and now I have this options:

```
d2j-dex2jar -- convert dex to jar
usage: d2j-dex2jar [options] <file0> [file1 ... fileN]
options:
 -d,--debug-info              translate debug info
 -e,--exception-file <file>   detail exception file, default is $current_dir/[fi
                          le-name]-error.zip
 -f,--force                   force overwrite
 -h,--help                    Print this help message
 -n,--not-handle-exception    not handle any exception throwed by dex2jar
 -o,--output <out-jar-file>   output .jar file, default is $current_dir/[file-na
                          me]-dex2jar.jar
 -os,--optmize-synchronized   optmize-synchronized
 -p,--print-ir                print ir to Syste.out
 -r,--reuse-reg               reuse regiter while generate java .class file
 -s                           same with --topological-sort/-ts
 -ts,--topological-sort       sort block by topological, that will generate more
                           readable code
 -v,--verbose                 show progress
version: reader-1.15, translator-0.0.9.15, ir-1.12
```

I would like to convert the `classes.dex` file to `classes.jar` can anyone advise me how to do this?

```
d2j-dex2jar [options] <file0> [file1 ... fileN]
```

Comment: What is your question?? What don't you understand in the dex2jar help output?

Comment: I don't know how to use the command `d2j-dex2jar [options] <file0> [file1 ... fileN]` to output the dex to jar

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I tried that, it converts it to .jar but the file is empty

Answer (score 0):

./d2j-jar2dex.sh classes.dex -o output.jar