# Downloading an embedded video inside an android application

Tags: android, video, youtube, download

How can i download or find the link for a video that embedded in android application? btw videos are not from youtube, just embedded videos.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So what you are trying to do here is called **Reverse  Engineering**. If you want to Download a video embeded inside a app, you first have to find the URL. So I suggest you to use [Dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases) and [ApkTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to decode the apk and dig inside the code and grab the URL and download it.

> How to Decode a APK? see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project)

P.S.:- I'm assuming that you are comfortable in using Android Studio and you have basic command line knowledge.