# Advice on reverse engineering Chinese app for BLE protocol

Tags: android, bluetooth, wearables

Recently I got a Chinese clone of the Mi Band 2. [The app it needs is horrible, though](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yc.bee&hl=en). So I wondered how to create another app that interprets the data from the band into something more useful (I know it's possible because even the mi band has alternative, user-created apps).

I started trying to reverse engineer the apk to find most of the code that is used to communicate with the BLE device. (Inspired by [this thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/xiaomi-mi-bluetooth-le-band-protocol-t2963581) on how someone did it with the mi fit app)

So I followed the accepted answer on [this stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project)

(Note that I downloaded the apk from a page called [APKTurbo](http://www.apkturbo.com) as it was the only option I found, and I have no way of copying the app from my device.)

I followed the steps mentioned above, but I only found three files on the .jar file created ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m8OG.jpg)).
All three can be found here:

- [StubApp.class](https://gist.github.com/VarhdVohrs/ea223880702fa374352d614c87e1d763)
- [QHDialog.class](https://gist.github.com/VarhdVohrs/287bd00cb5e91e33be4a2f8505ad03e2)
- [Configuration.class](https://gist.github.com/VarhdVohrs/1270b11c25818101470536671c801756)

There are mentions of something like *"com.qihoo360.crypt.entryRunApplication"*. (Qihoo is a Chinese security company).

I must mention I have *some* experience with Java, I have developed very basic apps for Android, but I am no expert, unfortunately.

So from what I found my only guesses are that either the app is encrypted or the place from where I got it adds some way of protection.

Next I tried using [this app called BLE Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner&hl=en) to read the band. I found that the name of the BLE device is RB09_heart. I also found 4 services, if I recall correctly, 3 of them were custom and only one was for the data of the band (e.g. name of device).

I don't know what to do with this data, I think I still need to see the app's code to understand how messages are send to the band.

What should I do next? Or, where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note what you trying to do is similar to what this author did for the Daydream controller: https://hackernoon.com/how-i-hacked-google-daydream-controller-c4619ef318e4 It may give you ideas for approaches.

Comment: Hi Jacob! Have you succeed with app?

Comment: I gave up on it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to reverse engineer an APK that's likely been minified/obfuscated, have you tried looking for an SDK for the bands?  Checking git turned up both [this](https://github.com/pangliang/miband-sdk-android/tree/master/app) and [this](https://github.com/dkhmelenko/miband-android) as potential options, do these not provide what you need?

Comment: I'm not asking for the miband protocol, because the clone I'm speaking of uses another one, and another app. Sorry if I was not clear enough. Thanks. Also worth adding that I have searched for the clone's protocol but I didn't find anything.

Comment: From what I'm seeing there probably isn't much difference.  Someone has also done so with the MiBand 2 here https://github.com/aashari/mi-band-2.  Since the communication isn't encrypted you can sniff the device's attributes and read/write them like a normal BLE device it seems.  What is the application you are trying to reverse engineer?

Comment: It  is [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yc.bee&hl=en)