# Lost my code, is it possible to find a way to recover it back?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, cell

I made my final degree's job an app using Android Studio.
My computer has been stolen and all my work is lost, but i have the app-debug.apk in the last final version (at least i had done the backup of this).

So, my question is: 
Is anyway to find my main code using the app-debug?

Thank you!

Comment: Why in the world weren't you using source control?  There's dozens of places to host a small repo for free.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

[Reverse engineering from an APK file to a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project)

However, all of your comments in the code will be gone and the variable names will be different.